# How to create an NSarray with NSAttributedStrings but keeping the attributes within the array?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I want to store different strings with different attributes and store all of them in one array and then display the objects in one label but each object with its respective attribute.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Solution derived from rmaddy's answer

```
NSDictionary *redAttrs    = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]};
NSDictionary *greenAttrs  = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.118 green:0.506 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000]};
NSDictionary *orangeAttrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor orangeColor]};

NSString *stringUm = @"Brazil";
NSString *stringDois = @"USA";
NSString *stringTres = @"England";

NSMutableAttributedString *redString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringUm];
[redString setAttributes:redAttrs range:NSMakeRange(0,4)];

NSMutableAttributedString *greenString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringDois];
[greenString setAttributes:greenAttrs range:NSMakeRange(0,2)];

NSMutableAttributedString *orangeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringTres];
[orangeString setAttributes:orangeAttrs range:NSMakeRange(0,4)];


NSArray *myStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:redString, greenString, orangeString, nil];

NSLog(@"%@", [myStrings description]);

NSMutableAttributedString *result = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]init];
NSAttributedString *delimiter = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @", "];
for (NSAttributedString *str  in myStrings) {
    if (result.length) {
        [result appendAttributedString:delimiter];
    }
    [result appendAttributedString:str];
}

_lblUm.attributedText = result;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. But based on your comment to gerrytan's answer, your goal is clearer.

If you have an array of `NSAttributedString` objects, then you can create a single string by appending them all together with an `NSMutableAttributedString`.

```
NSArray *myStrings = ... // your array of NSAttributedString objects
NSMutableAttributedString *result = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
// Put this delimiter between each string - change as desired
NSAttributedString *delimiter = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@", "];
for (NSAttributeString *str in myStrings) {
    if (result.length) {
        [result appendAttributedString:delimiter];
    }
    [result appendAttributedString:str];
}

myLabel.attributedText = result;
```

Comment: You got my point. But still I have one question: using your example, will 'myStrings' also hold the attributes each object have or just the objects? Because I must have the object AND the attribute.

Comment: I stated that `myStrings` has an array of `NSAttributedString` objects. I have no idea what you mean by "the object AND the attribute". This is why your question is so unclear. You need to provide more info in your question.

Comment: Ok, suppose i have 5 attibutedstrings each one is a country and each country has a different color being the attribute. My first goal is to store those strings in an array or dictionary. My first question comes here: is it possible to store attributed strings in array or dictionary?? Than I need to display in one uilabel all objects from the array or dicitionary but they must be displayed with their corresponding attributes. Using my example it would be a label displaying fife contry names and each one with a different color.

Comment: Create an `NSAttributedString` for each country and put that in an array (`myStrings` in my answer). If each of those attributes strings is created with each country's name and attributes, you will get what you want using the code I posted.

Comment: Humm, ok, I'll try that and post the results. Thank you rmaddy.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it gives me an error. The code and error is on the question.

Comment: THe problem is you are passing the wrong variables to your `myStrings` array. it should be `NSArray *myStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:redString, greenString, orangeString, nil];`.

Comment: I corrected that and then returns error again which is the new edit.

Comment: You are passing `greenAttrs` instead of `greenString`. Same with `orangeAttrs` instead of `orangeString`.

Comment: Wowowowo sorry for the dumb error!!! And Thanks for helping me!! Now it is working!!! I reedited and the code is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

UILabel only supports one NSAttributedString. I think what you can do is to place multiple UILabel side by side for each string on the array

Comment: Yes I know that but I know I can display the contents of an array in one label like converting its description into an nsstring and then displaying all objects in the label. The problem is: can I store many nsattributedstrings in an array or dictionary and display all of them in one label with the attributes, got it?  But thanks for the reply.

Comment: Well maybe you can extend UILabel and write your own class -- call it UILabelMultiString or something. Then override the part where it render the string to support multiple NSAttributedString.